# Are there any good ubuntu books out there?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Are there any good books for linux ubuntu sever out there?

I'm not sure if "The Official Ubuntu Server Book" is any good and I don't want to order a-waste-of-time. What I would really like is one that explains the ins-and-outs of commands. How to manage and maintain a secure box; explaining iptables, downloading form the net and unpacking compressed files, moving directories ect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you actually want a general linux administration book, not something specific to Ubuntu. In all actuality, aside from a few distro-specific commands for installing packages, managing rc/init scripts, managing an ubuntu server is just like managing any other linux distro.

So, for a general linux administration book, I'd highly recommend the [Rute Tutorial](http://rute.2038bug.com/rute.html.gz). Yes, it's been around for over 10 years now, but the basics of managing a system haven't changed. There is still a ton of great information in Rute, and what you learn from reading it will be applicable to any linux system you touch going forward.

For a quick guide on IPTables, I'd recommend [IPTablesRocks](http://www.iptablesrocks.org/). That will give you a good overview of IPTables' structure, and from there, you can either roll your own firewall rules or use one of the many IPTables "helper" scripts.

Comment: iptablesrocks.org is parked free.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice book on Amazon: [Ubuntu Hacks: Tips & Tools for Exploring, Using, and Tuning Linux](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596527209).

Answer (score 0):

[The Official Ubuntu Server Book (2nd Edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0137081332) looks like it might be worth checking out.